# Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request. Jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins

I tried to follow the instructions from YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8AQTlHoBKc on how to install Jenkins Agent on Windows as a service. Unfortunately, the service didn’t start.

How I see the terminal interface:

```
c:\jenkins>agent.exe install
2022-10-28 15:12:15,387 INFO  - Installing service 'Jenkins agent (jenkins8080agent)'...
2022-10-28 15:12:15,394 ERROR - A service with ID 'jenkins8080agent' already exists.
2022-10-28 15:12:15,396 FATAL - Failed to install the service. The specified service already exists.

c:\jenkins>agent.exe start
2022-10-28 15:12:24,461 INFO  - Starting service 'Jenkins agent (jenkins8080agent)'...
2022-10-28 15:12:24,987 INFO  - Service 'Jenkins agent (jenkins8080agent)' started successfully.

c:\jenkins>agent.exe status
Stopped
```

When it's done manually through Services app, the "Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request" exception occurred.

When I follow the same steps on other nodes, everything works, but when it's done on this particular one, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The code I used in .xml file that worked was:

```
<service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins continuous integration system.</description>
  <executable>java</executable>
  <arguments>-jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins.org.abc:8080/computer/abc%2Dauto/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 445322ae43dcc8b1f46d08b -workDir "c:\automation\jenkins"</arguments>
  <log mode="roll"></log>
</service>
```